# iOS7.1 LocationManager pausing when entering background (works in 7.0)

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Slightly confused on this one so I broke it down to a test app.

Simple singleton handling locationManager.  I have turned on location support in the background under capabilities.  Map is also enabled.

**The location manager is running all the time** but as soon as I put the application in to the background, it pauses.

I have read many posts about people trying to start location manager in the background, but mine is already running.  I assumed by enabling it under capabilities, it would continue to run in the background.  As soon as the app resumes, so does location manager.

Do I need to start looking in to beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler?

**UPDATE**

The code works in 7.06 and not 7.1.1? what did they change?

Comment: Nope, which iOS you're running ? if it's iOS7.0.x try iOS7.1.x

Comment: You put me on the right lines, it works in 7.0 and not 7.1

Comment: It seems that they've changed something in 7.1, just read the docs or release notes

Comment: Do clean and run your app again, I've feeling that your plist in not being compiled, just give a try

Comment: It appears I was having a bad day and background refresh was turned off :( I am a very stupid man!

Comment: No big deal it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you must set your applications background modes to allow location updates. To do this edit your apps .plist file and add "location" as a "Required background mode" see the Apple docs for more background modes [(here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22)

Answer (score 1):

in appDelegete.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [locationmanger startUpdatingLocation];//start your location update method here

//then add this code 
 backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundTask];
    }];
}

-(void) endBackgroundTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

it will work now